# Cannot login to minio behind nginx proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, minio

I cannot login to minio console behind nginx proxy. Both are started as docker container with docker compose. I can login to minio without proxy by accessing localhost:9001, but I cannot when behind proxy. I got response 401 invalid login, though I am using the same login as without proxy. Nginx configuration is mostly taken from minio docs. Can any one see the reason or know what can I check to login?

Part of docker compose:

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - ${FORWARD_NGINX_HTTP_PORT:-80}:80
      - ${FORWARD_NGINX_HTTPS_PORT:-443}:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
    networks:
      - default
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    command: minio server /data/minio --console-address ":9001"
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mc", "ready", "local" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
    expose:
      - 9000
      - 9001
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: ${MINIO_ROOT_USER:-minio}
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD:-password}
      MINIO_SERVER_URL: https://s3.localhost
      MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL: https://s3.localhost/minio/ui
    ports:
      - ${FORWARD_MINIO_API_PORT:-9000}:9000
      - ${FORWARD_MINIO_CONSOLE_PORT:-9001}:9001
    volumes:
      - minio-data:/data
    networks:
      - default
```

Part of nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name s3.localhost;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.key;

    ignore_invalid_headers off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_request_buffering off;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        chunked_transfer_encoding off;

        proxy_pass http://minio:9000;
    }

    location /minio/ui {
        rewrite ^/minio/ui/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        real_ip_header X-Real-IP;

        proxy_connect_timeout 300;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Origin '';

        chunked_transfer_encoding off;

        proxy_pass http://minio:9001;
    }
}
```

Certs generated with mkcert.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working configuration. The Minio console is served at https://127.0.0.1/.

```
├── docker-compose.yml
└── nginx
    ├── nginx.conf
    └── ssl
        ├── localhost.crt
        └── localhost.key
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    command: server --console-address ":9001" /data
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: minio
    volumes:
      - data:/data
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mc", "ready", "local" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minio
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: password

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    hostname: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - minio

volumes:
  data:
```

`nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

events {
}

http {
    include                 /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type            application/octet-stream;

    sendfile                on;
    keepalive_timeout       65;

    upstream console {
        server minio:9001;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name s3.localhost;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.key;

        ignore_invalid_headers off;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_request_buffering off;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
            proxy_connect_timeout 300;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;

            proxy_pass http://console;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]